# Add class to html via admin select

Tags: magento-1.9

I developed a simple admin panel for my magento theme ( I'm back in Magento ) and wanted to know how I can add a class html via descent in Magento admin . E ' can add it through array ? if so, how can I do ?

Comment: Can you clarify just what you're asking here?

Comment: Hi, sorry for my english, i want to add a class in frontend via admin panel. I want to put a drop down menu in admin, where i can select two or more option. If I select option one, magento add class X, if select option 2 , magento add class Y.

Comment: Then you can use getConfig() to retrieve options from admin. I'll answer below with an example later

Comment: Meant `getStoreConfig()` above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good tutorial on how to create admin options: http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/01/30/add-custom-settings-in-magento-admin-panel/

Once you have created your admin option, you can get the option's value with `Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName');`

Then use it to generate your class dynamically, something like:

```
<?php $class = Mage::getStoreConfig('mySection/myGroup/myField'); ?>
<div class="<?php echo $class; ?>" ></div>
```

You could get creative and use a PHP ternary operator to set a default class:

```
<div class="<?php echo ($class=='new-class') ? 'new-class' : 'default-class'; ?>" ></div>
```